# cannot find solution for my webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2008

I am new to .net and I have downloaded VS 2008 trail version today. I was trying to develop a web service.

I added a new project and selected asp.net web service application.Then i wanted to add a new project to the same webservice but i was unable to find solution for my webservice in the solution explorer, to right click on it and add a project. It only shows webservice, then properties and references below it. Do I need to make any changes in the settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, why not use Visual Studio 2010? It also has a trial version.

Secondly, you shouldn't be using the "ASP.NET Web Service Application" for new development. That's now a legacy technology. Use the "WCF Service Application" instead.

Finally, the default is to not show the solution if there is only one project. In Tools->Options->"Projects and Solutions", check "Always show solution".